# At what value(s) of $x$ does $ \cos(x) = 7x$?

Tags: calculus

For some reason, this question was posed to me on a calculus quiz, and I have completely drawn a blank on how to solve this problem.

If someone could explain how to solve this problem, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

At what value(s) of $x$ does $\cos(x) = 7x$?

Comment: In a *calculus* quiz? Are you sure they asked for exact values as opposed to intervals in which there are solutions and/or solutions accurate to a certain decimal place?

Comment: @JohnM: That would certainly make identifying an exact solution easier! `:)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use Newton's Method to get a solution to arbitrarily high precision.
$$\begin{align}
x_0&=1\\
x_1&=1-\frac{7(1)-\cos(1)}{7+\sin(1)}
\approx0.17621353\ldots\\
x_2&\approx0.17621353\ldots-\frac{7(0.17621353\ldots)-\cos(0.17621353\ldots)}{7+\sin(0.17621353\ldots)}
\approx0.14151392\ldots\\
x_3&\approx0.14151392\ldots-\frac{7(0.14151392\ldots)-\cos(0.14151392\ldots)}{7+\sin(0.14151392\ldots)}
\approx0.14143076\ldots\\
x_4&\approx0.14143076\ldots-\frac{7(0.14143076\ldots)-\cos(0.14143076\ldots)}{7+\sin(0.14143076\ldots)}
\approx0.14143076\ldots\\
\end{align}$$

So to eight decimal places, the solution is $x\approx0.14143076\ldots$.

---

If you have studied Maclaurin polynomials yet in calculus, you can use the following. A visual inspection of the graphs of these functions should convince you that the solution is small, smaller than $1/7$ even. for such $x$-values, Maclaurin polynomials for $\cos(x)$ are fairly accurate. So your equation to solve is pretty close to this one: $$1-\frac12x^2=7x$$ which is equivalent to $$x^2+14x-2=0$$ which has two solutions: $$-7\pm\sqrt{51}$$ One of these is small and positive, so that is the one we are looking for: $$x\approx-7+\sqrt{51}\approx0.14142843\ldots$$

You can even use Taylor's inequality to put a bound on how far off this is from the real solution.

---

This last method can be made even *more* accurate if you use the fourth degree Maclaurin polynomial for $\cos(x)$, since technically, fourth degree polynomial equations can be solved by hand using the Ferrari-Cardano method. That process is too long to detail here, but if you start with $$1-\frac12x^2+\frac{1}{24}x^4=7x$$ you can deduce that $$x\approx0.14143076\ldots$$

Comment: I should've known, lol! Newton's Method was part of the subject of the quiz. Now it makes sense. Thank you very much!

Comment: @SageHopkins Oh good. Just for fun, about to post another option ;)

Comment: @SageHopkins Another option posted. By the way, if this was literally what the question asked on a quiz, it would have been better had it asked you for a decimal approximation of the solution. Even the Newton approach does not _really_ solve the equation.

Answer (score 2):

I will post an alternative iterative method.

Define a recurrence relation so that $a_0 = 1$ and $a_n = \dfrac{\cos(a_{n-1})}{7}$.

The solution to the problem is:

$$x = \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n.$$

The convergences of this series requires other math (Lipschitz constant satisfying certain conditions, etc.).

This may not work on a Ti-84 because of a lack of precision.

Answer (score 0):

We can approximate a solution $a$ of the equation $\cos x = 7x$ using Newton's Method. First observe that a solution to this is the same as a zero of the function $f(x) = 7x - \cos x$. So we'll apply Newton's method to $f(x)$, but we'll need to begin with a good starting value $x_0$.

Just by thinking about how the functions $y = 7x$ and $y = \cos x$ grow, you should be able to see immediately that any and all zeros of $f(x)$ must occur near $x = 0$. Indeed, since $-1 \leq -\cos x \leq 1$ for all $x$, you know that $7x - 1 \leq f(x) = 7x - \cos x \leq 7x + 1$. So if, for example, $x > 1/7$ you know that $0 = 7(1/7) - 1 < 7x - 1 < f(x)$, and similarly $f(x) < 0$ if $x < - 1/7$. So a safe bet for $x_0$ would be $x_0 = 0$ or $x_0 = 1$. Applying the formula $x_{n+1} = x_n - f(x_n)/f'(x_n)$ repeatedly will give you better and better approximations of one solution to this equation. (Now a question for you is: Is there only one such solution? Why?)

Answer (score 0):

For variety...

Let $f(x) = \cos x - 7x$, and let $\alpha$ be the value $f(\alpha) = 0$. Let $g(x)$ be the inverse of $f(x)$ on an interval containing $\alpha$ and $0$.

Then, we have $g(0) = \alpha$ and $g(1) = 0$.

$$g'(x) = \frac{1}{f'(g(x))} = \frac{1}{-\sin g(x) - 7 } $$

so we have the differential approximation

$$ g(x) \approx g(1) + g'(1) (x-1) = \frac{1-x}{7}$$
$$ g(0) \approx \frac{1}{7} $$

and, in fact, we have

$$ f\left(\frac{1}{7} \right) \approx -0.01018673955$$

Answer (score 0):

As the other answerers point out, you can approximate the solution using Newton's method. But note that there are an infinite number of solution in the complex plane and there are exact expressions involving the roots. E.g., if S is the set of all the (complex) solutions of $\cos(z) = 7 z$, then:

$$\sum_{z\in S}\frac{1}{z^2} = 50$$

$$\sum_{z\in S}\frac{1}{z^3} = \frac{707}{2}$$

$$\sum_{z\in S}\frac{1}{z^4} = \frac{7498}{3}$$

The solution closest to the origin is the real solution and this then makes the largest contribution the above summations. A good approximation to the real root x is obtained by putting $ 1/x^4 = \frac{7498}{3}$, this gives $x\approx 0.1414308$.

An advantage of this method is that you can easily obtain a very good approximation to the root expressed as an nth root of a rational number without having to use a calculator.